# Declaring a char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a login/register project and I have difficulties in declaring the `char* tempUsername` from this code (SIGSEVG segmentation fault)

```
char *tempUsername, *tempPassword, *tempPasswordConfirm, *tempSecurityQuestion;

/*
no other declaration for tempUsername here
*/

std::cout<<"Enter your new username:\n";
std::cin>>tempUsername;

//process stops here

        if(fileSearch(newFilename(tempUsername))) {
            std::cout<<"Username already exists! Choose another username!\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout<<"Enter your password:\n";
            std::cin>>tempPassword;
            std::cout<<"Confirm your password:\n";
```

I'm having a hard time understanding anything about pointers, so any advice is more than helpful!

Comment: Your pointers don't refer to any valid memory. You need to fix that

Comment: Pointers point. They're a variable that holds the location of another object.  If a pointer doesn't point to a valid object, there isn't much you can do with it. Can we talk you into using `std::string`?

Comment: Since you are having issues with `char` pointers, I recommend using `std::string`.

Comment: Hmm, as I understood, I can use a char* as an array of chars, is that true? I would have to change the whole thing from char* to string but if that fixes it, I'm all for it.

Comment: With pointers, you have to allocate memory that they point to.  When you declare a pointer, it doesn't point to anything.  You have to make it point to *something*, like `new char` or maybe a hardware device.

Comment: @VicVerevita _I would have to change the whole thing from char* to string but if that fixes it, I'm all for it._ Go for it! :)

Comment: The really tricky thing here is even after you point `tempname` at a valid buffer, `std::cin>>tempUsername;` won't know where to stop reading and will gleefully overfill the buffer and do unholy things to the memory past the buffer. One of the many reasons you want to use `std::string`.

Comment: *I can use a `char*` as an array of chars, is that true?*  **No**, that is not true.  You can use a `char*` as a pointer to an array of chars.

Comment: The most recent versions of C++ will infer the size of an array, if you use an array, and stop before overfilling the array. This won't work with a pointer to an array because pointers just point. They have no idea how much stuff they're actually pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> char *tempUsername
> ```

> ```
> std::cin>>tempUsername;
> ```

The problem here is that your pointer is uninitialised. When you try to extract from the input stream into the uninitialised pointer, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Don't do this.

Your goal seems to be to read a string of user input. A solution that I can recommend is to use the `std::string` class:

```
std::string tempUsername;
std::cin >> tempUsername;
```

No need to use a pointer to achieve this.

> I can use a char* as an array of chars, is that true?

It is not true in general. If you have a `char*` that points to an element of an array of `char`, then you can use that `char*` as an iterator to access the elements of the array.